# How to make unsigned integer signed in assembler?

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm writing a small NASM (64-bit) program in which I use linux lseek syscall. I want to move to specified offset in a file. This offset is stored in the memory, but it's an unsigned number. And lseek requires a signed one.

How to easily "translate" unsigned number to signed number in NASM? Or maybe I'm totally wrong and I don't need to do such conversion?

Comment: Indeed, you don't need to do anything, unless your unsigned number might be out of range for signed, but you'd need a pretty big file for that ;)

Comment: Thank you, my code wasn't working properly and I thought the problem was with the sign, but it seems that I'm just too tired to find the bug :P

Comment: You can check this particular issue using `strace`.

Comment: Wow, thank you again! I'm a beginner and I've never heard about it :D